Facing issue while running refresh.bat file in nswag in asp net zero
I am using asp net zero For updating the frontend's service.proxy.ts file I need to run the nswag/refresh.bat file
but while running it gives error while hitting the url to see the swagger documentation. It also giving error So the api documentation is not being generated. But asp net zero configured the swagger setup
The error from console:

PS D:\Nswag upated strategia\src\Strategia.Web.Host\nswag> nswag run
NSwag NPM CLI
NSwag command line tool for .NET Core Net80, toolchain v14.1.0.0 (NJsonSchema v11.0.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))
Visit http://NSwag.org for more information.
NSwag bin directory: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nswag\bin\binaries\Net80

Executing file 'D:\Nswag upated strategia\src\Strategia.Web.Host\nswag\service.config.nswag' with variables ''...
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure, CallSite, Object)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid1[T0](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at NJsonSchema.Infrastructure.DynamicApis.HttpGetAsync(String url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NSwag.OpenApiDocument.FromUrlAsync(String url, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/NSwag.Core/OpenApiDocument.cs:line 235
   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.FromDocumentCommand.RunAsync() in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Generation/FromDocumentCommand.cs:line 62
   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.FromDocumentCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Generation/FromDocumentCommand.cs:line 53
   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocumentBase.GenerateSwaggerDocumentAsync() in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagDocumentBase.cs:line 270
   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocument.ExecuteAsync() in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagDocument.cs:line 67
   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.ExecuteDocumentAsync(IConsoleHost host, String filePath) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Document/ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 76
   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Document/ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 49
   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessSingleAsync(String[] args, Object input)
   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args, Object input)
   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagCommandProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagCommandProcessor.cs:line 65node:child_process:965
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: dotnet "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nswag\bin/binaries/Net80/dotnet-nswag.dll" run
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:890:11)
    at Object.execSync (node:child_process:962:15)
    at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nswag\bin\nswag.js:62:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:414:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:303:5) {
  status: 4294967295,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 2112,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}

I want to run nswag file so that it will update the service.proxy.ts file in angular in asp net zero

Please share a [mcve]. And please, please, please, please - format your question to be readable.

And please: No Images of text

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am using asp net zero
For updating the frontend's service.proxy.ts file I need to run the nswag/refresh.bat file
but while running it gives following error
while hitting the url to see the swagger documentation It also giving error
So the api documentation is not being generated.
But asp net zero configured the swagger setup.
